# Drupal8 Currency Module, How to configure in my content type and views?

Tags: currency, drupal-views, drupal-8

I installed the Currency module in my localhost, i really in need of the currency converter dynamically.

1. I store the currency value in USD on my field and shown as its in my view of table format.
2. For Customer, view of currency drop-down will be there, if the user selects the currency the value it need to be convert from USD to AUD, AUD to NZD etc., like this.
3. Kindly Provide me solution whether the currency converter gets the latest exchange rate and currency value.

Need for support

Answer (score 0):

**If you use [Coorrency - Currency Converter](https://www.drupal.org/project/coorrency) module ,then this is the stratergy**

> if you use a free service then the rates are refreshed every 30
>   minutes.

**if you use a Premium service then the rates are refreshed every 15 minutes.**

[image: Pricing]